# How to insert column with lambda function

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I need to update new columns of dataframe df.
"Lvalue" column  is same as "word" column value
But problem to update "Rvalue" column
It must contain value of previous one row value of word column

```
word    Lvalue Rvalue
Hello,  Hello, 
how     how   hello
are     are   how 
you      you   are

df['Lvalue'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.word, axis=1)
```

How to write for Rvalue

```
df['Rvalue'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.word, axis=1) ## this need correction
```

Comment: Please give an expected output. I think `loc` with `shift` might work better here.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `.shift()` method in pandas, this takes the selected column and creates a copy shifted down by 1 in the index:

```
df['Rvalue'] = df["Lvalue"].shift(1)
```

Also worth saying that you can set `"LValue"` more efficiently simply using:

```
df["LValue"] = df["word"]
```

Comment: You are the the pro! I did not know about the `shift` method till when I saw your answer.

Comment: How can i add condition to compute Lvalue column only if "word" column value ends with period.   df["LValue"] = df["word"]( if it ends with period[ie .])

Comment: @SUHASINIKL that's possible, but I think that should be asked as a separate question rather than me trying to describe in the comments